# Set value in enum field

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

In django, you should use this as an enum field in your model (if I understand correctly, I am not working that long with Django):

```
class Car(models.Model):
  TYPE = ( ('SUV','race') )

  type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE, default='SUV', max_length=20)
```

Later, in a filter, I can use this:

```
suvs = models.Car.objects.filter(type='SUV')
```

But this means a simple typo (`SUB` instead of `SUV`) can lead to an error, which isn't tackled by the code. Is there a way around this? Something perhaps like

```
suvs = models.Car.objects.filter(type=models.Car.TYPE.SUV)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-choices](https://github.com/bigjason/django-choices) package for behaviour like this. Using that, you can do:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    class CarType(DjangoChoices):
        SUV = ChoiceItem('something')
        BUS = C('something else')

    type = models.CharField(choices=CarType.choices, default=CarType.SUV, max_length=20)
```

And use it later like:

```
suvs = models.Car.objects.filter(type=models.Car.CarType.SUV)
```